# Unable to sudo apt upgrade properly on Ubuntu-Budgie facing isuses with Python-Samba upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, python, samba

Hi I am new to Ubuntu and I am loving it already. I had just checked for update on Ubuntu-Budgie (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS) and during update I had encountered with the following error.

Here is the scneraio, I tried this command - `sudo apt upgrade` and I get the following output

> ```
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> Calculating upgrade... Done
> The following packages will be upgraded:
>   python-samba
> 1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> 1 not fully installed or removed.
> Need to get 0 B/1,919 kB of archives.
> After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
> (Reading database ... 365163 files and directories currently installed.)
> Preparing to unpack .../python-samba_2%3a4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb ...
> /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-samba.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-samba.prerm: pyclean: not found
> dpkg: warning: old python-samba package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
> dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
> /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: pyclean: not found
> dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-samba_2%3a4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb (--unpack):
>  new python-samba package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
> /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-samba.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-samba.postinst: pycompile: not found
> dpkg: error while cleaning up:
>  installed python-samba package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>  /var/cache/apt/archives/python-samba_2%3a4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
> ```

I tried the following commands in addition to fix this based on google search

```
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt remove python-samba
sudo apt install --reinstall python-samba
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

But my bad nothing worked still I get the same output could you please help me in understanding and fixing the issue. Thanks.

## UPDATE 1

As per the comments tried this command - `sudo apt install python-minimal` and I got the below errors

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-minimal is already the newest version (2.7.15~rc1-1).
python-minimal set to manually installed.
Suggested packages:
  python-gpgme
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python-samba
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,919 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 365163 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-samba_2%3a4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-samba.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-samba.prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: warning: old python-samba package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-samba_2%3a4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new python-samba package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-samba.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-samba.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python-samba package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-samba_2%3a4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

## UPDATE 2 and SOLUTION

I tried the following commands and it worked for me based on provided solution.

```
sudo apt-get -m --reinstall install python python-minimal dh-python
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt install --reinstall python-minimal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have errors about missing `pyclean` & `pycompile`

> ```
> /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-samba.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-samba.prerm: pyclean: not found
> ...
> /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: pyclean: not found
> /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-samba.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-samba.postinst: pycompile: not found
> ```

Both are included in `python-minimum` package. Probably, you removed it manually.

Try reinstalling it:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python-minimal
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I tried that what you have mentioned and I got the same list of error. Attaching the details in the question.

Comment: @Abhi, how about `sudo apt install --reinstall python-minimal`

Comment: Thank you user.dz, It worked :) Thanks for your kind help

Comment: @Abhi , you welcome :), would you be kind and accept the answer as it worked for you.